# discord bot message deletion for any message, performance question

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I implemented a short function to go to a channel and delete the message history, and it works fine, but it's very slow.  The bulkDelete function only handles the <2w old messages, and if we didn't keep on top if it, well, here comes the bot to the rescue.

This code works, but as I said it's really slow.  I'm thinking it's because the deletion is  a single call, it has to complete, and then likely has to notify any and all members on the server of a refresh etc. if they happen to be in the same channel etc.

Any suggestions on a speed up?

```
    let numDeleted = 0;
    bot.channels.fetch(message.channel.id)
        .then(chan => {
            chan.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] })
                .then(msgs => {
                    message.send(`Deleting ${msgs.size} messages (lesser of request or existing message history)`);
                    // console.log(msgs.filter(msg => msg.deleted === false));
                    const m = msgs.filter(msg => msg.deleted === false);
                    m.forEach(element => {
                        // console.log(element);
                        element.delete()
                            .then(()=> numDeleted++)
                            .catch(err => console.error(err));
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

thanks!

Comment: `.fetch()` and `delete()` are asynchronous and send REST requests to the Discord API Endpoint. Which means, it's taking a certain amount of time to complete the task (Sending the request -> receive a reply from API endoint). In this case you are looping through all channels and messages, so that might take a while to complete.

Comment: @Variable do you have an alternate suggestion?